# timer for 3:30 mins which has a options with add and skip?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am a newbe in ios so i want help in making a timer for 3:30 mins which has two options with add and skip which will disappear after the timer reaches to 00:00. Please help me i am in a very difficult situation right now.

This is for the timer

```
-(void)updatelable:(NSTimer *)timer {

    remainingTime=180;

    for (int i=remainingTime;i==0 ;i--) {

        NSInteger minutes = floor(*(remainingTime))/ 60;
        remainingTime = remainingTime-(minutes*60);

        NSInteger seconds = remainingTime;

        second.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld",seconds];
        minute.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld",minutes];

        timerLabel.text = @"Time up!!";
    }

    [timer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show the code and explain what it does wrong. If you haven't tried anything then you need to go and read some tutorials.

Comment: @Wain i have posted the method which will update the timer .please see it and tell me whats wrong with this code.

Comment: You're always setting the same time and invalidating the timer... Explain what you observe, and show the code that sets up the timer. Think about how answerable your question is - help us to help you...

Comment: what is your idea about putting a fast-enumeration inside the timer's callback method? the original concept is wrong, because literally you are just enumerating from `180` to `0` in a fragment of a sec...

Comment: @holex can you give me some ideas regarding this?

Comment: @Sushrita, you may check my answer below. :)

Comment: Do you want to show a timer clock on UI ?

Comment: @Mrunal yes i want to show a timer  clock on UI can you help?

Comment: @Sushrita Check this its a good tutorial and example code also available to download. http://www.raywenderlich.com/25561/learn-to-code-ios-apps-3-your-first-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

.h file

```
{
    int counter;
    NSTimer timer;
}
```

in .m file

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     counter = 210;//total Time
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];        
 }


-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer*)timr
{
     if(counter == 0)
     {
         [timer invalidate]
         //set label hidden here after 3:30 minutes
     }
     //strTime is string containing remaining time
     NSString *strTime = [self formatTimeFromSeconds:counter];
     counter--;
}
```

for Label text call this method

```
 -(NSString *)formatTimeFromSeconds:(int)numberOfSeconds
{
    int seconds = numberOfSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (numberOfSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours = numberOfSeconds / 3600;
    //we have >=1 hour => example : 3h:25m
    if (hours)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dh:%dm:%ds", hours, minutes, seconds];
    //we have 0 hours and >=1 minutes => example : 3m:25s
    if (minutes)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm:%ds", minutes, seconds];
    //we have only seconds example : 25s
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ds", seconds];
}
```

Comment: thank u for your help It's working fine but can you tell me how to set this on labels for min:sec like this 3:30.

Comment: I have tried this for showing the minutes and the seconds on the UILabel :            NSInteger minutes = counter/ 60;
        NSInteger seconds = counter-(minutes*60);
        second.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld",seconds];
        minute.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld",minutes];             If there is any mistake please tell me .

Answer (score 1):

it is not the most sophisticated way, but it does to job for you and it shows precisely how such thing should work in practice:

```
static NSInteger remainingTime = 210;

// ...

- (void)startTimer {
    [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(counter:) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE] fire];
}

- (void)counter:(NSTimer *)timer {
    remainingTime--;

    NSLog(@"%02ld:%02ld", (NSInteger)(remainingTime / 60.0), (remainingTime % 60));

    if (remainingTime == 0) {
        // times up!
       [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: at this line   NSLog(@"%02ld:%02ld", (NSInteger)(remainingTime / 60.0), (remainingTime % 60));
some error is showing i.e :invalid operands to binary expression('int *' and 'double')

Comment: I'm not sure where you have got that message from, this snippet is live and functioning, it works as is; anyway the log line is optionally prints the time to the console does not affect the concept, you can remove it freely. be aware of the `remainingTime` is `NSInteger` not `NSInteger *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 counter =10;//total Time
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer*)timr
{
if(counter == 0)
{
    [timer invalidate];


    //set label hidden here after 3:30 minutes



     [second setHidden:YES];
     [minute setHidden:YES];
     [colon setHidden:YES];
     [skip setHidden:YES];
}

NSInteger minutes = counter/ 60;
NSInteger seconds = counter-(minutes*60);


second.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld",seconds];
minute.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld",minutes];
counter--;
}
```